# I have a goal in mind

Tags: word, poetry

> My prefix has a purpose 
>    My suffix together with two letters is a homophone for somewhere dark and deserted 
>    My infix is an atom gained an electron 
>    I am an adverb and I have a goal in mind

What word am I?

Clue 1: (Given 7 hours later)

> What the word is can be deduced by the first and last line

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Could you please double-check whether the clues you’ve provided matches the solution you have in mind?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Yes, it is, I made my riddle by referring to the word written on paper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am:

> Intentionally

My prefix has a purpose:

> An *intent* implies an objective

My infix is an atom gained an electron:

> A (negative) *ion* (anion)

My suffix together with two letters is a homophone for somewhere dark and deserted

> *ally*, if you add *v* and *e*, you get valley, which is darker than a plain and most of them are deserted at the feet of a mountain

I am an adverb and I have a goal in mind

> *Intentionally* is clearly goal-motivated